# Checking if some string is in form field's labels in django template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to make a base template for forms which 3 or 4 forms extend. Some of the forms have DateFields for which I need to include jquery for rendering the datepicker. 
What I need is that if the form being rendered has a field with label containing 'date' then include jquery otherwise not. I have tried the following 2 approaches but had no success

```
{% if 'date' in form.fields.label|lower %}
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
{% endif %}
```

and

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% ifequal field.label|lower 'date' %}
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

I have also used `label_tag` instead of `label` but no success. 
What is the correct way of achieving this?

Comment: I don't know if it works but did you try using `field.html_name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider to use the [form assets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/media/) mechanism for this task.

Answer (score 0):

> field.html_name

is work 1.10

---

forms.py

```
class import_csv_form(forms.Form):

  fieldName = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.NumberInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'min':'0', 'max':'10', 'value':'0'}),
        label='Label text')
```

Form template

```
{% if field.html_name == "fieldName" %}
   Do something
{% endif %}
```